# Prepared statement is returning empty results, possible syntax error

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

When I execute the prepared statement the results are returned empty. If I copy and paste the statement into phpMyAdmin it executes properly. `$_SESSION['userGroup']` has been checked and confirmed to contain the proper value but `$systems` remains undefined.

Am I missing something?

```
        $stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT `Systems` FROM `groups` WHERE `GroupID` = ?");
            echo $mysqli -> error;

        $stmt -> bind_param('i', $_SESSION['userGroup']);
        $stmt -> execute();
        $stmt -> store_result();
        $stmt -> bind_result($systems);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try

```
$stmt -> bind_param('i', $_SESSION['userGroup']);
$stmt -> execute();
$stmt -> bind_result($systems);
$stmt -> fetch();
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for. I had just been looking at it too long. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I missing something?

you are missing documentation and/or tutorial to learn from.
Where you can learn the proper syntax that should include

```
$stmt -> fetch();
```